# Lua Code "tester"

Tags: lua

I'm looking for some good Lua code 'tester' online, where I could paste my code and run it to see if the code is ok itself and if its running fine, as expected.

It CAN be online tools, but I didnt say that I not accept any Windows applications which will do the same job.

I have searched a lot, but didnt find anything interesting, so I don't really know if something like this is available.

Comment: It's not LUA; it's Lua. It's a proper name, not an acronym.

Comment: @Nicol weeeeell, actually it used to stand for Linguagem para Usario de Applicao :) But its not an acronym any more, though it used to be.

Comment: The luac.exe program will compile a Lua script without running it. It'll produce errors if anything is wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can run code online at both [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) and [codepad.org](http://codepad.org)

Comment: Wow, both sites are great! Thank you! (`You can accept this answer in 8 minutes...`).

Comment: wow, ideone.com has [brainf**k](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/bf/) and [intercal](http://catb.org/~esr/intercal/)

Comment: I like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php for testing, you can use more than one file